# Convert Hexadecimal to Decimal in AVR Studio?

Tags: c, hex, decimal, avr

How can I convert a hexadecimal (unsigned char type) to decimal (int type) in AVR Studio?

Are there any built-in functions available for these?

Comment: When it comes to integer types, hexadecimal and decimal are just different representations for humans, the actual data is always binary. So whether you write, for example, `0x0A` or `10` in the source code makes no difference when it is compiled.

Comment: `unsigned char b = 0x??; int i = b;`

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly do you mean by "a hexadecimal (unsigned char type)"? An ASCII representation of a single hexadecimal digit? A string (i.e. an array of ASCII chars)? Or just a binary number, as suggested by others here? An example may help.

Comment: But when I perform arithmetic operations, I do not get the expected result. So how do I convert a Hex string (which I receive as using serial communication) to the corresponding integer?

Comment: Try `sscanf(hex_string, "%x", &my_unsigned_int);`, or `my_int = strtol(hex_string, NULL, 16);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On AVRs, I had problems using the traditional hex 2 int approach:

```
char *z="82000001";
uint32_t x=0;
sscanf(z, "%8X", &x);
```

or

```
x = strtol(z, 0, 16);
```

They simply provided the wrong output, and didn't have time to investigate why.

So, for AVR Microcontrollers I wrote the following function, including relevant comments to make it easy to understand:

```
/**
 * hex2int
 * take a hex string and convert it to a 32bit number (max 8 hex digits)
 */
uint32_t hex2int(char *hex) {
    uint32_t val = 0;
    while (*hex) {
        // get current character then increment
        char byte = *hex++; 
        // transform hex character to the 4bit equivalent number, using the ascii table indexes
        if (byte >= '0' && byte <= '9') byte = byte - '0';
        else if (byte >= 'a' && byte <='f') byte = byte - 'a' + 10;
        else if (byte >= 'A' && byte <='F') byte = byte - 'A' + 10;    
        // shift 4 to make space for new digit, and add the 4 bits of the new digit 
        val = (val << 4) | (byte & 0xF);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Example:

```
char *z ="82ABC1EF";
uint32_t x = hex2int(z);
printf("Number is [%X]\n", x);
```

Will output:
[image]

EDIT: sscanf will also work on AVRs, but for big hex numbers you'll need to use "%lX", like this:

```
char *z="82000001";
uint32_t x=0;
sscanf(z, "%lX", &x);
```